# Sparc v440 unable 2 boot after recommended patch install

Tags: solaris, oracle, solaris-10, sparc

After installing the October 2011 recommended patch bundle on a Solaris 10 the host fails to boot. The output is

```
{0} ok boot

SC Alert: Host System has Reset

screen not found.
keyboard not found.
Keyboard not present.  Using ttya for input and output.


Sun Fire V440, No Keyboard
Copyright 1998-2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
OpenBoot 4.10.10, 8192 MB memory installed, Serial #54744555.
Ethernet address 0:3:ba:43:55:eb, Host ID: 834355eb.



Rebooting with command: boot                                          
Boot device: /pci@1f,700000/scsi@2/disk@0,0:a  File and args: 
\
Evaluating: 
Out of memory
Warning: Fcode sequence resulted in a net stack depth change of 1 
Evaluating: 

Evaluating: 
The file just loaded does not appear to be executable.
{3} ok
```

If I do a `boot -F failsafe` the host come up and I'm able to mount the root device (ufs on `/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0`) and nothing appears broken, i.e I can see the logfiles from the patch install etc. Root device still have 1GB+ free. 
Only 2 kernel patches was installed from the patch bundle: 144500-19 & 147440-02.

Any hints how to debug it further, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The system that has this same issue for us is a V880
Removing these patches:

```
143643-04 requires 144500-19
147440-02 kernel patch
147713-01 requires 144500-19
147436-01 requires 144500-19
147434-01 requires 144500-19
147266-01 requires 144500-19
144500-19 kernel patch
```

Fixed my boot up problem! But now we are 2 kernel updates behind and Oracle does not have a fix for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

How were the patches applied?

In single user, multi-user, or via LU into an ABE?

Issue may have been from installing 2 kernel patches w/out a reboot in between?